# Dynamic Inclusion of JS/CSS in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am looking for options to dynamically include JS/ CSS (at request processing time) based on request parameters, similar to `<jsp:include>` for JSP.

Comment: have a look at templates like ejs or handlebars ,you will be able to achieve the same thing

Comment: Thanks. I have created a wrapper jsp file that just includes the asset. Something, like index.jsp : <%@include file="index.js">